# Determining when karma-pact mock server has started

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, karma-runner, pact

We're using the karma-pact plugin to run our pact JS client tests, based on the example from https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/karma/mocha/client-spec.js .

In the example there's a timeout in the before(), I believe to ensure the mock service has started before running the tests (see comment  "required for slower Travis CI builds").

I'm reluctant to set a fixed timeout in our tests as it'll either be too short or too long in different environments (e.g. CI vs local) and so I was looking for a way to check if the server has started.

I'd tried using the pact API https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-node#check-if-a-mock-server-is-running , however this appears to start a new mock server which conflicts with the one started by the karma-pact plugin (an Error: kill ESRCH error is reported when trying to run pact.createServer().running from within a test).

Is there a way to determine if the mock server has started up e.g. by waiting for a URL to become available? Possibly there's a way to get a reference the mock server started by the karma-pact plugin in order to use the pact-node API?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the simplest way is to wait for the port to be in use.

[Karma Pact](https://github.com/pact-foundation/karma-pact/blob/master/index.js#L11) by default will start the Mock on port `1234` (and you can specify your own). Once the port is up, the service is running and you can proceed.

For example, you could use something like [wait-for-host](https://github.com/Chris927/wait-for-host) to detect the running mock service:

```
var waitForPort = require('wait-for-port');

waitForPort('localhost', 1234, function(err) {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
  // ... Mock Service is up - now we can run the tests
});
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll give that a try. Am I right in thinking there's the (small) possibility that the [isPortAvailable function](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/src/common/net.js) will be using the port while the mock server is trying to start up, and prevent the mock server from starting?

Comment: Actually that function is the exact opposite of what you want - quite right. It is actually used to determine if port is free before starting the server. Hopefully you get the idea though! I'll update the answer

Comment: Right, it's the opposite we're looking to do. I do have a nagging feeling using this method might cause the mock server to fail to start (as the check opens up port 1234, albeit briefly).

Comment: Yes there is definitely a high chance of conflict, that's why you wouldn't use this method. I've updated my response to clarify the position.

Comment: Unfortunately our tests run within PhantomJS which doesn't have the 'net' node package. Also tried the 'wait-for-url' npm package which also requires net.

Comment: We've written a small utility function to wait for the URL to become available (via ajax calls) and then to call provider.removeInteractions() - any other ideas would be welcome, of course

Comment: That sounds about right. Will be keen to see what you ended up with!